# react Native firebase authentication Persisting issue

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am using this React Native firebase library [React-native firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage). whenever I reload the app or restart, the simulator I have to sign in again and user data is not saved in the emulator memory as the documentation says. in the documentation it says "On web-based applications, the Firebase Web SDK takes advantage of features such as cookies and local storage to persist the users authenticated state across sessions. The native Firebase SDKs also provide this functionality using device native SDKs, ensuring that a users previous authentication state between app sessions is persisted.

The user is able to clear their state by deleting the apps data/cache from the device settings. "
this is my authUserSlice

```
    import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const initialState = {
  authenticated: false,
};

const authUserSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authUser',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: build => {
    build
      .addCase(getAuthUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.authenticated = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(signOutUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.authenticated = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export default authUserSlice.reducer;

export const getAuthUser = createAsyncThunk('authUser/get', async data => {
  const {email, password} = data;
  try {
    await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    console.log('user logged in');
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error', error);
  }
 
});

export const signOutUser = createAsyncThunk('signOut/get', async () => {
  try {
    await auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => console.log('User signed out!'));
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
});
```

this is my navigator

```
    import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
    import AuthNavigator from './AuthNavigator';
    import RooteNavigator from './RooteNavigator';
    import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.authUser.authenticated);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {!user ? <AuthNavigator /> : <RooteNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

I am expecting the user data to be save in the emulator memory and not to be prompted to sign in every time I reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved the issue. I had to change my navigator to the following

```
const AppRouter = () => {
const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
const [user, setUser] = useState();
// const user = useSelector(state => state.authUser.authenticated);

// Handle user state changes
function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
  setUser(user);
  if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
 const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
 return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
}, []);

if (initializing) return null;
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    {!user ? <AuthNavigator /> : <RooteNavigator />}
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
};
```